# Spotlight is disabled but "._file_name" still get created on external drives that I plug in

Tags: spotlight, filesystem, file, flash-memory

I want to prevent my MAC from creating ._file_name files on external memory drives that I plug into it. I think I've turned off Spotlight completely. However, such files keep getting created. How to fix that?

Comment: The Finder creates those files, not Spotlight.

Comment: @GlenYates, how to prevent finder from creating them?

Comment: They're created because whatever filesystem is on the storage device you plug in doesn’t support extended attributes/resource forks.